# Pull up keyboard while scrolling UITableView and scroll along with the tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uikeyboard

To add panning behaviour to the keyboard, I am using [DAKeyboardControl](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl). It works just fine (after modifications) for panning behaviour to close the keyboard.

How do I make the keyboard appear if the user tries to scroll downwards (finger pan in up direction) at the end of the `UITableView`. To be more specific, I am looking for behaviour similar to the Facebook Messages app, where, if you scroll up the keyboard appears, with panning, and scrolls *with* the table.

**EDIT**: It seems I am not clear about what I want. I wish to move the keyboard *along* with the scrollview (`UITableView`). In the following image, I am *panning* the keyboard *along* with the table. The table is already scrolled to it's bottom, and if I try to scroll down any further the keyboard begins to appear. My finger, meanwhile, is in the middle of the table.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This effect can be achieved by setting the scrollview's `keyboardDismissMode` to `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive` and then in `scrollViewDidScroll:` calling `[textField becomeFirstResponder];`. Because you are in the middle of scroll, the keyboard will respect the `keyboardDismissMode` property and interactively appear. Drop the `DAKeyboardControl`; it's outdated.

Comment: I suspected this, but didn't actually try it. Just one issue: DAKeyboardControl has a `keyboardTriggerOffset` that I use to begin panning gesture if touch reaches a textView above the keyboard. Is there some way a similar value can be set with `keyboardDismissMode`?

Comment: You should have the text view as an accessory view. Then, `keyboardDismissMode` takes the accessory view into account.

Comment: Doesn't work. The keyboard appears with it's normal curve, and not with the scrolling effect.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer Interesting. I'll take a look a bit later.

Comment: This is the best solution. Its only downside — iOS 7 only.

Answer (score 1):

You need an element such as `UITextView` and then, detect the scroll (for example, using any of the `UIScrollView` delegate methods). Once scrolled, call `becomeFirstResponder` on the text view.

Answer (score 0):

add this in .h file…

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat lastContentOffset
```

And add this in your .m file...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender 
{
   if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y)
   {
       [textField becomeFirstResponder];
   }
   else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) 
   {
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
   self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

}
```

Hope this will do the trick, haven't tested it...